# For loop error checking

Tags: c#, asp.net

Everything works, the one thing that is not working is it is making a note for every single account even if nothing was done/found for that account.

```
for (int j = 0; j < accounts.Length; j++)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand("insert into TableHistory (id, startDate, dueDate, userid, amount, number, needsReview, offer, dateAdded, dateRejected, rejectedBy) " +
                       "select (select max(id) + 1 from Table1), startDate, dueDate, userid, amount, number, needsReview, offer, dateAdded, GETDATE(), @userID from Table1 where number = @number " +
                       "delete from Table1 where number = @number", connection);
            SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(accounts[j].ToString());
            SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userID;

            connection.Open();

            SqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

            NoteAccount note = new NoteAccount("Personal Note", accounts[j].ToString(), userID);
            note.makeNote();
        }
```

Lets say Account 11 does not have anything in `Table1`.  Nothing will fail, because the insert statement won't fire because the select statement returns nothing from `Table1`, this is fine.

But the `note.makeNote();` fires and adds a "personal" note to the account when doesn't need to be added.  Is there an easy way to only add the note if the account exists in `Table1`?

Comment: check the return value of ExecuteNonQuery, it is supposed to return you the number of affected records, then you can use an if and call or avoid calling note.makeNote();

Comment: @James: On a side note, you need not open/close the connection, create a new command in the loop. Take a look at `using` block on how to use resources esp. connections/command such that it will be cleaned up once done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` will return you the number of rows affected so You can put your check on the basis of that. if it is greater than 0 then make a note.

```
if(SqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
{
   NoteAccount note = new NoteAccount("Personal Note", accounts[j].ToString(), userID);
   note.makeNote();
}
```

Comment: Damn you beat me by 36 seconds.

Comment: Do I need to have SqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery two times, or will it actually run from within the if statemnt?

Comment: @JamesWilson don't need to run two times. it will run within if statement. but close connection after this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly I think you can use the return result of `ExecuteNonQuery`. This returns the number of rows affected by the query therefore you can test that it is greater than 0 and only make a note if it is.